# Hudson change HUDSON_URL

Tags: url, hudson

I use Hudson  on my computer and I work in a network. The Hudson Url is following: http://192.168.0.73:8080.

I want to change the Hudson URL to `192.168.0.55:8080`.
How can I do it ?

Comment: Does your computer have several ethernet interfaces?

Answer (score 1):

This is configurable through hudson's web interface.  Go to the "Configure Hudson" link (after logging into hudson with administrative rights).  Then go to the global settings link.  hudsonURL is configurable there.

Answer (score 0):

If `192.168.0.73` is the ip address of your computer (which you can check by typing `ipconfig`), then you cannot change it.

The only solution would be to run Hudson (`java -jar hudson.war`) from another computer with the IP address `192.168.0.55`.

Comment: Alternatively, they can assign another IP address to the same physical machine that is currently used to run Hudson. A network administrator should be able to do this easily.

Comment: @Bernard: true, but in a corporate environment like mine, ... err, no you cannot.

Comment: I had more luck than you. However, I didn't wanted another IP, I wanted to have another hostname. Both have the same IP, but that is not an issue, since we do not publish the IP address. So in the future we can move one of the hostnames to a different hardware or VM and Hudson will still have the same hostname, even though it is a different IP. -- My recommendation is to stay away from IP addresses as much as possible since they have more disadvantages than advantages compared to hostnames. Any current application (also many older apps) accept hostnames instead of IP adresses.

Comment: @Peter: actually, the Hudson server (master) I set up on Unix has both a unix 'hostname' (different from the actual server name) and a unique IP. That way, I can switch from one physical Unix server to another (in a cluster-mode backup mode) and keep the same 'hostname' and IP.

Comment: We are not that sophisticated. Our Hudson is not clustered, since it is not business critical. I am working for an insurance with own development department. Worst case: we can setup a virtual machine in 3 hours and move Hudson (from backup). The new Hudson master will be up in less than a day. :) But I like virtual IPs that move to the active cluster member when running in cold standby mode. However, I once saw freaky effects, after moving an physical IP to new Hardware. The switches cached the old MAC address and forwarded the traffic to the old machine (which had a new IP).

Answer (score 0):

you can change the ip address of the system where hudson is running and can keep this as static.